# Converting array to shape drawn: Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500, 700))
Shape=['.....',
       '..O..',
       '.OOO.',
       '.....',
       '.....']
ShapeProperites={'x': 250,
                 'y': 50,
                 'Color':Red}
```

How can I convert this array in Pygame to a shape drawn on a screen with the properties from the dictionary? The list is meant to represent a tetromino. The 0's should be drawn as squares on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want your characters to represent, or where you want X and  Y to be located, but something like the following should get you started.

First of all, you want to declare the color: `Red = (255, 0, 0)`

Then, in your draw loop you want to render the shape with the following code:

```
x = ShapeProperties["x"]
y = ShapeProperties["y"]
for line in Shape:
    for character in line:
        if character == "O":
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, ShapeProperties["Color"], pygame.Rect(x, y, Size, Size))
        x += Size
    y += Size
    x = ShapeProperties["x"]
```

It starts at the position you've specified in the properties. It then iterates over the lines in  the shape, and then over the characters that denote the actual shape. Each character increments X by the `Size`, which you can set to be whatever size you want your shape blocks to be. Once then end of a line is reached, it resets X and increments Y by the size, moving onto the next row.

As an optimization you might want to consider rendering this into a surface of a `Shape` class, and just blitting that surface each frame, instead of re-rendering the whole shape, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: When I run the code, this error is generated. Sorry, I am new to programming so please do help. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....PROJECT\Shapes.py", line 60, in <module>
    y = ShapeProperties['y']
NameError: name 'ShapeProperties' is not defined

Comment: Yes, that's a very basic variable naming error, as the error message states. I fixed a typo in your code.

Comment: You need to rename your `ShapeProperites` to `ShapeProperties`.